# Overriding types using 'type' keyword and path-dependant types

Tags: scala, types

Let's say I have a peace of code like this:

```
trait  Holder  {
  type Value
  def put(v:Value)
}

class JsonHolder extends Holder {
  override type Value = String
  def put(v: JsonHolder.this.Value): Unit = {}
}

class XmlHolder extends Holder {
  override type Value = String
  def put(v: XmlHolder.this.Value): Unit = {}
}

object Foo {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val jsonHolder = new JsonHolder
    val xmlHodler = new XmlHolder
    val valueOfJson = new jsonHolder.Value("AAA")
    val valueOfXml = new xmlHodler.Value("AAA")
    jsonHolder.put(valueOfXml)
  }
}
```

I don't get why this compiles. Shouldn't jsonHolder.put(valueOfXml) by a type error?

If I change

```
type Value
```

to something like this:

```
case class Value(content:String)
```

and remove the override lines and everything else stays as it is type mismatch error will actually show up.

So what is the difference between those two, since declaration of put argument does not have to change and the behavior is completely different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, that's not a type error, because both `JsonHolder.Value` and `XmlHolder.Value` are `String`s. Consider the `type` an alias for an other type. All types are replaced with their actual types. So your code roughly looks like this:

```
val valueOfJson = new String("AAA") // JsonHolder.Value is a String
val valueOfXml = new String("AAA") // XmlHolder.Value is a String as well
```

And like this:

```
class JsonHolder extends Holder {
  def put(v: String): Unit = {}
}

class XmlHolder extends Holder {
  def put(v: String): Unit = {}
}
```

If one of your types would be, for example, an `Int` then sure you'd get a compilation error:

```
class JsonHolder extends Holder {
  override type Value = Int
  def put(v: JsonHolder.this.Value): Unit = {}
}

class XmlHolder extends Holder {
  override type Value = String
  def put(v: XmlHolder.this.Value): Unit = {}
}

object Foo {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val jsonHolder = new JsonHolder
    val xmlHodler = new XmlHolder
    //compilation error here - Int doesn't have a String constructor
    val valueOfJson = new jsonHolder.Value("AAA") 
    val valueOfXml = new xmlHodler.Value("AAA")
    jsonHolder.put(valueOfXml)
  }
}
```

Comment: OK so `type` behaves just like a simple string substitution during compilation, and all occurrences are just replaces and there is no "intelligence" there.

So is it possible to do something like this:

instead of `case class Value` change it to `abstract class Value` and then override it in the other two classes so I could alter some behavior of the `Value` class?

Comment: Could you please describe what are you trying to achieve with this? The first thing I'm thinking of is parametrization - `Holder[T]`, and classes like `JsonHolder extends Holder[String]`. But I suppose you already considered this and it probably doesn't suit your case

Comment: Actually this is not the case that I have any kind of problem. I was just playing with what I can and cannot do with path-dependant types.

Comment: Since Scala has this rare feature where type can rely on actuall variable instance I was trying to see what can be achieved with it. 

What I was thinking of is to have an option to change the type in child classes and it worked with the `type` keyword. But when you use the same type there you have the initial problem - mismatch error does not show up. 

When I use a case class then you cannot alter it in children.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a language lawyer, but it seems to me that `type` in Scala can be said to be a type *alias* declaration, so that in your code, `JsonHolder.Value` and `XmlHolder.Value` are actually both the same type, i.e. `String` and `new jsonHolder.Value(...)` (or `new xmlHolder.Value(...)`) is equivalent to `new String(...)`, so that `valueOfJson` and `valueOfXml` are both inferred to be `String`s. Since `JsonHolder.put` and `XmlHolder.put` both take a single String argument, the code typechecks.

However, once you replace `type Value = String` with a case class, JsonHolder.Value and XmlHolder.Value cease to be the same type, as per the rules on path-dependent types. Now the put functions no longer have the same signature and the values have different types as well, hence the type mismatch error.