# Override toString of a scala type

Tags: scala, tostring

I have a type in Scala:

```
  type Fingerprint = Seq[(Int, Int)]
```

I would like to override the `toString` of this type. How can I do this?

Comment: I think you don't have a type here, you have an alias. So you cannot override anything there because you don't declare a type. If you inherited from the type => then you could override.

Comment: You are not actually creating a type here. You are just creating an alias for a type. Read this to clarify - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306233/overriding-types-using-type-keyword-and-path-dependant-types/21306691#21306691

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are good reasons to use a type class-based approach to this kind of problem instead of Scala's `toString` (which is arguably just an unpleasant hand-me-down from Java), and the fact that you can't bolt a `toString` on an arbitrary type is one of them. For example, you could write the following using [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz)'s `Show` type class:

```
import scalaz._, syntax.show._

implicit val fingerprintShow: Show[Fingerprint] = Show.shows(
  _.map(p => p._1 + " " + p._2).mkString("\n")
)
```

And then:

```
scala> Seq((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)).shows
res0: String = 
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

There are also good reasons to prefer a type class-based approach to one based on implicit classes or other implicit conversions—type class instances are generally much easier to reason about and debug.

Comment: scalaz is awesome, but adding a massive library for a print is a bit overkill.

Comment: @flavian: Agreed, and rolling your own `Show` is pretty trivial—I only used Scalaz's as an easy example.

Answer (score 5):

Overriding `toString` may not be the best option here, but there is a simple alternative:

```
implicit class SeqAug[T <: (_, _)](val seq: Seq[T]) {
   def showInfo: String = {
      seq.map(p => p._1 + " " + p._2).mkString("\n") // or whatever you want.
   }
}
val x = Seq(("test" -> 5))
Console.println(x.showInfo)
```

You can even restrict the bound of the augmentation:

```
type Fingerprint = Seq[(Int, Int)]
implicit class SeqAug(val fingerprint: Fingerprint) {
  // same thing
}
```